# Distinct 2 field AS one column SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

can i SELECT distinct 2 fields (provfrom, provto)  on table AS one column 
with condition :
- values of 2 fields is never same in one row
- values in field provfrom can be inside field provto but in different row
- values in field provto can be inside field provfrom but in different row

example :
i have 2 column as below

```
 -------------------------
|  provfrom   |  provto   |
 -------------------------
|  2          |    4      |
|  3          |    7      |
|  3          |    7      |
|  5          |    2      |
|  5          |    2      |
|  7          |    2      |
|  7          |    2      |
|  1          |    5      |
|  2          |    5      |
|  2          |    8      |
|  5          |    8      |
 -------------------------
```

the result that i want by disticnt is as below

```
 -------------
|  prov       |
 -------------
|  1          |
|  2          |
|  3          |
|  4          |
|  5          |
|  7          |
|  8          |
 -------------
```

Can i do this in sql server?
i try to found out by explore google, but not found it

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Union` keyword which will give `distinct` elements from Both Tables

```
select provfrom  from mytable
union 
select provTo   from mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either do this with a `union` or by using `apply`, the apply has less IO so I would go with the apply query.

```
create table #temp
(
    provfrom tinyint,
    provto tinyint
);

insert into #temp (provfrom, provto) 
       values (2,4),(3,7),(3,7),   
              (5,2),(5,2),(7,2),   
              (7,2),(1,5),(2,5),   
              (2,8),(5,8); 

set statistics io on;

select distinct 
    a.provfromto
from #temp as t
cross apply (values (t.provfrom),(t.provto)) as a(provfromto);

select provfrom from #temp
union 
select provTo from #temp

set statistics io off;
drop table #temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t.prov
from 
    (select provfrom as prov
    from yourtable
    union
    select provto
    from yourtable) as t
order by t.prov
```

`UNION` function apply a distinct clause, so you'll get all value per one occurence.

The external query about ordering your result set